# Error with redux-promise : Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm actually trying to use redux-promise, and when i send a request to my api in my action, i get this error.

[image]

I saw that there was a speaking subject to the same error but I have not found my problem solving in responses.

**So this is my code :**

**./app.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import reducers from './reducers/app-reducer'
import routes from './routes'

import promise from 'redux-promise'

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);


ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
                <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
                </Provider>, document.querySelector('.container'))
```

**./reducers/app-reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import user from  './user-reducer'


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    user: user
})

export default rootReducer
```

---

**action whose called :**

**./actions/user-actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const UPDATE_TOKEN = 'UPDATE_TOKEN'
export const CREATE_SESSION = 'CREATE_SESSION'
export const CREATE_SESSION_ERROR = 'CREATE_SESSION_ERROR'

export function createSession(obj){

    if (typeof obj === 'string') {

        return {
            type: UPDATE_TOKEN,
            payload: obj
        }
    }
    else {
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080' + '/session', {
            data: {'Email': obj.email, 'Password': obj.password},
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then((response) => {
            return {
                type: CREATE_SESSION,
                payload: response.data
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            return {
                type: CREATE_SESSION_ERROR,
                payload: error
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I've also tried with redux-thunk, I get the same error.

Someone you have an idea ? or maybe do I take me wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating ajax calls in actions, you should use redux-thunk and compose.

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
```

Change your store like this:

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(applyMiddleware(thunk))(createStore)(reducers);
```

And set axios to use dispatch:

```
return (dispatch) => {
   axios.post('http://localhost:8080' + '/session', {
      data: {'Email': obj.email, 'Password': obj.password},
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
   }).then((response) => {
      dispatch ({
         type: CREATE_SESSION,
         payload: response.data
      })
   }).catch((error) => {
      return {
         type: CREATE_SESSION_ERROR,
         payload: error
      }
   })
}
```

Comment: Yes I had found solution a short time after posting my problem, but thank you for posting an answer for people who can meet it ;)